# Repeat a string with a subscript over a given range in python

Tags: python, string

I've a string 'abc', and a number 5. I need to generate ['abc1','abc2','abc3','abc4','abc5'].

Is there a quick way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try list comprehension:

```
['abc' + str(x) for x in range(1, 6)]
```

In general if you have `my_string` and `my_integer`:

```
[my_string + str(x) for x in range(1, my_integer + 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)

```
s = 'abc'
N = 5
delim = ''

out = [delim.join([s, str(i+1)]) for i in range(N)]

print(out)
# ['abc1', 'abc2', 'abc3', 'abc4', 'abc5']
```